# Existing Account not matching during Lead conversion process

Tags: account, lead-conversion, conversion, matcher, duplicate-matching-rule

I'm having an issue with existing account matching during the Lead conversion process.
In this example, I am using the **Standard Lead Duplicate Rule**; with a custom account matching rule with the following Matching Criteria:

> Account: NameFUZZY: COMPANY NAMEMatchBlank = FALSE

It is not suggesting the existing accounts (image 3), but when I click on the search box it then suggests the correct accounts (image 4).

I don't understand why existing accounts are not being suggested. Has anyone else has similar issues?

Image-1:
[image: image-1.]

Image-2:
[image: image-2]

Image-3:
[image: image-3]

Image-4:
[image: image-4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity I set this up and was able to reproduce your issue. After some looking around, I found this response from the trailhead community and after trying out their suggestion, I can confirm it worked for me at least (expected accounts are proactively suggested on the conversion screen). Bold emphasis added for the important bits:

> Hi, I also encountered such a problem and an answer from Carlos helped
> me to  > deal with it - so basically it is not enough to have a
> Duplicate Rule on Lead > looking at Account (this only will show
> potential duplicates when creating /  viewing Lead record). **You also
> need to have a Duplicate Rule just on Account (comparing Accounts with
> Accounts) - only then the Account will be suggested in the Lead
> Conversion window as a potential match.**

[Link to thread](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8RHuSAN)

Also, though the above didn't specify this, it only worked when I used a **custom** account matching rule, not the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is struggling with this as I was, I had to re-order some of my rules, and moving particular ones higher up in priority allowed the suggestions to appear in the lead conversion window.